# Не меняется цвет кнопки если контрол динамический

Tags: c#, winforms

Задача при нажатии на кнопку создать еще одну кнопку с определенным цветом кнопки.
 Добавляем на форму кнопку при нажатии на которую мы создаем кнопку с заданным цветом.

```
    private static int X = 100;
    private static int Y = 100;
    private void buttonDynamic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddButton(X, Y);
        X += 100;
    }
private void AddButton(int x, int y)
    {
        // создаем контрол
        System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonDyn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button(); 
        // устанавливаем необходимые свойства
        buttonDyn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);           
        buttonDyn.Name = "button1";
        buttonDyn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        buttonDyn.TabIndex = 0;
        //вот здесь меняем цвет кнопки
        buttonDyn.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
        buttonDyn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // button1_Click - функция обработчик события нажатия на кнопку
        buttonDyn.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click); 
        Controls.Add(buttonDyn); // добавляем на форму

    }
```

При нажатии на кнопку buttonDynamic появляется новая кнопка, но цвет ее стандартный серый. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство [BackColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) относится к так называемым [AmbientProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ambientproperties(v=vs.110).aspx). Смотрите [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7).

Его значение задаётся таким же, как у родительского контрола (это сделано для облегчения конструирования: добавляем контрол - его параметры определяются автоматически).

Пока контрол не добавлен на родительский, нет смысла менять такое свойство. Его нужно менять после добавления.

```
Controls.Add(buttonDyn);
buttonDyn.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
```